# Неправильно работает if когда в функции находится метод prompt

Tags: javascript

В любом случае срабатывает то, что в if неважно что было введено в prompt как с этим бороться?

```
var user

function login() {
user = prompt("Введите свой ID");
 alert(user);
  if ( user = "username") {
  alert("123")
 }
}
```

Comment: Исправьте `user == "username"`

Comment: @br3t Боже, как все было просто, спасибо!